# Looking for adding a app link in sharepoint ribbion to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am looking for a way to add a customized Add an App Link in the SharePoint Online Ribbon Modern pages

Any help will be appreciate i have attached a screenshot where i would like to add a link
e.g. i want to add a spreadsheet app i do not need to go all the way from settings and then add an app by searching for it

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

A lot of options are not available yet, but you can use:

[image]

Mind that the behaviour is different on classic sites with modern look, and modern-modern sites. On modern sites you might have to disable "noscript".

You can achieve this using PnP templates, e.g.

```
<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
  <Button
    Id="Ribbon.Templates.YourCompanySpreadsheet"
    Command="??"
    Image16by16="/_layouts/15/images/yourImage.png"
    LabelText="Amazing Spreadsheet"
    Description="This links directly to company spreadsheet app"
    ToolTipTitle="Spreadsheet"
    ToolTipDescription="This links directly to company spreadsheet app"
    TemplateAlias="o1"
    Sequence="15"/>
</CommandUIDefinition>
```

Have a look at a sample code and exact limitations to date:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

Comment: Keep Getting this Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Custom'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path C:\Users\tejast\Desktop\Xml Custo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.ApplyPro
   visioningTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Hope this article is helpful to you:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api

In addition, It's esay to add links to navigation in the site for your requirement:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca